# $(this).find('input[type="submit"]:not(.cancel), button').click(function () - what is this?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Can someone help me understand this line of jquery code?:

```
$(this).find('input[type="submit"]:not(.cancel), button').click(function ()
```

I'm particularly interested in `.cancel`, since the whole chunk of jquery code (not included here) is being used to validate a page and I'm trying to prevent the validation if the user clicks on the cancel button. I'm guessing the above line of code is saying it the submit button clicked is NOT the cancel button, then continue.

But I don't know how to designate a button as cancel.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Basically it is looking for elements located within `this` that has the following requirements

1. is an input
2. has type = submit
3. does not have a class of `cancel`

OR

1. is a button

Answer (score 9):

Good answers here. Perhaps this annotated version adds some value.

```
$(this)                   // within this jQuery object
  .find('                 // find all elements
    input[type="submit"]  // that are input tags of type "submit"
    :not(.cancel)         // and do not have the class "cancel"
    ,                     // or
    button                // are button elements
  ')
  .click(                 // and for each of these, to their click event
    function (){}         // bind this function
  );
```

Comment: i wish i could mark two items as an answer since this definitely did answer my question. But john answered first, even though you went into a little more detail. I gave you a upvote though. Thanks for going into the detail you did.

Comment: @merk, no problem. You should choose the answer that's best for you; I upvoted John's as well. I answer questions here not only to help, but to learn. There's no better way to cement one's understanding of even seemingly simple things than to try to explain them clearly to someone else.

Answer (score 2):

They're applying a CSS class named cancel to symbolize the cancel button basically (then checking it's a button with out this class)

<strike>Though I was un-aware you can use an asterisk (`*`) in a CSS class name.</strike>

*Nevermind, it was you trying to bold code within a code block*

I'm also curious why they make the cancel button of type submit when they want it to cancel anyways. (Seems like `<input type="button" ... />` would be a better fit).

Comment: The `**` were (I assumed) added for emphasis, and I've removed them as they were confusing.

Comment: Yeah you would think that it would use it as a wild card for the searching

Comment: Yup, got that now. It didn't click until after. Oops. ;p

Comment: oh, sorry about that - i did try to bold it, didn't dbl check to see that it did actually bold the text. apologies on the confusion

Answer (score 2):

`.cancel` is a class selector.  Specifically it is looking for `input` elements with the type attribute set to `submit`, but don't have the `cancel` class.  It also looks for elements with the tagName `button`.

You can "designate a button as cancel" like this:

```
<input type='submit' class='cancel' />
```

Answer (score 1):

basically it is selector which says
give me submit buttons without cancel class and buttons and apply click handler.
try to look up the following selectors

tag
.class
:not